# How to add an origin and destination search bar in mapbox for android

Tags: android, mapbox-android

Im new to mapbox and android development as well. This is a personal project and I've been trying to learn  all this stuffs.

I would love to know how to achieve this search box through mapbox. Any advice we'll be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8lUz.png

Comment: you can create your custom linear layout with orientation vertical and then create two edittexts into it. give top margin to layout .

Comment: Alright i'll try that.